# why python opencv only read the first frame from my webcam?

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, face-detection, resnet

i've tried to detect faces from my webcam , but it was only detect the first face which appeared in the first frame , then it will crush , i have used mtcnn to detection operation , after detecting the first face (if it exist ) then it will stop capturing and crushed and will remain on the screen, i've used jupyter notebook as editor and the notebook will remain loading ..
but it will work fine without using `mtcnn` detector !
but when there is no faces in the first frame it will raise this error
whenever i use `if boxes:` before `for box in boxes:`

> IndexError: list index out of range

but if there was a face it will raise this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

but i wont use `if boxes:` if there was not a face to detect 
it will raise this error :

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

and if detect a face in the first frame then it will remain loading after detecting the face!

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
while(True):      
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    frames_tracked = []
    print('\rTracking frame: {}'.format(i + 1), end='')
    frame_pil = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame_pil = Image.fromarray(frame_pil)
    boxes,_ = mtcnn.detect(frame_pil)
    frame_draw = frame_pil.copy()
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(frame_draw)
    for box in boxes:
        draw.rectangle(box.tolist(), outline=(255, 0, 0), width=6)          
        frames_tracked.append(frame_draw.resize((640, 360), Image.BILINEAR))      

    d = display.display(frames_tracked[0], display_id=True)
    i = 1     
    try:
        while True:
            d.update(frames_tracked[i % len(frames_tracked)]) 
            i += 1     
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    if cv2.waitKey('q') == 27:
        break
capture.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

please i have to complete my project for my final year project

Comment: "this is for the second time i post this issue"... I would say this is not a good starting point.

Comment: thank you , i updated , but please if you know a way to solve let me know @Berriel

Comment: If someone wants to know how to do this it was answered on: https://forums.fast.ai/t/face-detection-in-real-time-with-mtcnn-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-size/62363/19?u=hadus

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce it in my PC, but maybe an exception will make it:

```
import cv2  
i = 0
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
while(True):      
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    frames_tracked = []
    print('\rTracking frame: {}'.format(i + 1), end='')
    frame_pil = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame_pil = Image.fromarray(frame_pil)
    boxes = []
    boxes,_ = mtcnn.detect(frame_pil)
    frame_draw = frame_pil.copy()
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(frame_draw)

    try:
        for box in boxes:
            draw.rectangle(box.tolist(), outline=(255, 0, 0), width=6)          
            frames_tracked.append(frame_draw.resize((640, 360), Image.BILINEAR)) 
    except ValueError:
        print("Oops! ...")     

    d = display.display(frames_tracked[0], display_id=True)
    i = 1     
    try:
        while True:
            d.update(frames_tracked[i % len(frames_tracked)]) 
            i += 1     
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    if cv2.waitKey('q') == 27:
        break
capture.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If this doesn't work. Maybe just check if boxes is None?:

```
if boxes is not None:
    for box in boxes:    
        print("seems to work")
```

Comment: no still after detecting the first face in the frame it will remain loading , and whenever there is no face ( 'NoneType' object is not iterable)

Comment: You could try `if box is None` meanwhile. I'll try getting mtcnn so that i can fully test it in my PC

Comment: i tried it as well,as before after detecting the first face it will remain loading , you can get mtcnn from (pip install facenet_pytorch) > from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN ) i will appreciate you

Comment: @Ivan in case you were also interested in a solution: https://forums.fast.ai/t/face-detection-in-real-time-with-mtcnn-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-size/62363/19?u=hadus